# Find a continuous map between two sets of 2D points

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, image-processing, interpolation

Given two sets of points in 2D `points1` and `points2` inside a rectangle, I would like to find a continuous map `f` defined on the rectangle that sends `points1` to `points2`. The set of points are ordered, which makes it considerably easier (`points1[[i]]` should be sent to `points2[[i]]`).

```
{points1, points2, trianglesIndices} = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/n8teGNSM"] // ToExpression;
GraphicsRow[{ListPlot[points1], ListPlot[points2]}]
```

[image: point sets]

First, I made a Delaunay mesh and find the affine transformations on each pair of triangles:

```
triangles1 = points1[[#]] & /@ trianglesOrder;
triangles2 = points2[[#]] & /@ trianglesOrder;
```

Then, using `inPolyQ` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9417/18767) to defined a piecewise function, mapping each triangle to its image:

```
inPolyQ[poly_, pt_] :=  Graphics`PolygonUtils`PointWindingNumber[poly, pt] =!= 0
mats = Table[FindGeometricTransform[triangles2[[i]], triangles1[[i]], 
           TransformationClass -> "Affine"][[2, 1]], {i, Length@triangles1}];
f[{x_, y_}, coef_] := Piecewise[Table[{TransformationFunction[
  coef*mats[[i]] + (1 - coef)*IdentityMatrix[3]][{x, y}], 
      inPolyQ[triangles1[[i]], {x, y}]}, {i, Length@triangles1}], {x, y}]
```

We can check `f` maps `points1` to `points2`, with the parameter `coef` ponderating inbetween:

```
coef = 0;
Norm[func[#, coef] & /@ points1 - points1]
coef = 1;
Norm[func[#, coef] & /@ points1 - points2]
(* 0. *)
(* 7.50594*10^-12 *)
```

The problem is, it is *very very* slow when used with `ImageTransform` (code provided below).

I tried other approaches: transforming each triangle independently and assembling everything in the end, but I got to defaults because of the borders of the original image being giving spurious diagonals. I also tried making masks, making an affine transformation of the whoel original image for each triangle and applying the masks, then combining together. It almost works, but not totally, possibly because of some small margins that interfere.

Anyway, I believe I'm missing some simpler approaches, and that's my question.

---

Here is an example image if need be, consisting of a grid and the triangles whose vertices constitute `points1`:

```
width = 300;
height = 400;
start = Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Thick], Triangle /@ triangles1, 
   Thin, Black, Line@Table[{{1, h}, {300, h}}, {h, 1, 400, 10}], 
   Line@Table[{{w, 1}, {w, height}}, {w, 1, width, 10}]}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> {width, height}]

Show[start, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[points1]}, 
     PlotRangePadding -> None]]
```

[image: example]

Then, the final image can be obtained with `ImageTransform` but takes several minutes (!):

```
funcInv[{x_, y_}, coef_] := Piecewise[ Table[{TransformationFunction[
     coef*Inverse[mats[[i]]] + (1 - coef)*IdentityMatrix[3]][{x, y}],
     inPolyQ[triangles2[[i]], {x, y}]}, {i, Length@triangles2}], {x, y}]

(* very slow, but works *)
coef = 1;
final = ImageTransformation[start, funcInv[#, coef] &, DataRange -> Full]
Show[final, Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[points2]}, 
      PlotRangePadding -> None]]
```

[image]

Is there a faster approach?

Comment: [`FindGeometricTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindGeometricTransform.html) does precisely this.

Comment: @Roman Isn't `FindGeometricTransform`, that I am using on each triangle, limited to _linear_ (or affine) mappings?

Comment: It should be possible to define such a function directly in a way one does in Lagrange Interpolation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Texture` does the mapping between triangles on an Image instantaneously.

Here is your code (with `trianglesOrder` replaced by `trianglesIndices`) :

```
{points1, points2, trianglesIndices} = 
  Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/n8teGNSM"] // ToExpression;
GraphicsRow[{ListPlot[points1], ListPlot[points2]}]

triangles1 = points1[[#]] & /@ trianglesIndices;
triangles2 = points2[[#]] & /@ trianglesIndices;

width = 300;
height = 400;
start = Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Thick], Triangle /@ triangles1, 
    Thin, Black, Line@Table[{{1, h}, {300, h}}, {h, 1, 400, 10}], 
    Line@Table[{{w, 1}, {w, height}}, {w, 1, width, 10}]}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> {width, height}];
img00 = Rasterize[start]
```

[image]

Now use Texture :

```
Graphics[{Texture[img00], 
  MapIndexed[
   Polygon[#, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> ({#[[1]]/300, #[[2]]/400} & /@ 
        triangles1[[First[#2]]])] & , triangles2]}]
```

[image]

I didn't succeed in using `VertexCoordinateScaling`, which would be 
the right option to prevent the scaling of the coordinates systems 
( `{#[[1]]/300, #[[2]]/400} & /@ ...` )

`Texture` works also with polygons. In that case it decomposes the polygons in triangles. Of course the decomposition is somewhat arbitrary. [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179518/5467) is a utility to see how it works.