# Face Morphing with Mathematica

Tags: graphics, image-processing, animation

Can Mathematica be used to produce animations of face morphing (as described in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphing)?

*This is a self-answered question because I felt there was a lack of resources on this topic, to share funny stuff and benefit from experienced users' advice. Of course everybody is welcome to post an answer!*

Answer (score 44):

*MMA version: 12.0*

I'll use the following images, found on the internet under open licence (if you know how to share the images themselves, please let me know). I originally had chosen two more but feature extraction did not work appropriately. I already rescaled them by chosing scaling factor such that the area of the triangle "left eye - right eye - mouth" was constant.

[image]

These are stored in the `List` `imgs`. Then, the features are extracted (in `feats`). Notice that I dropped `"MouthInternalPoints"` because there were of no real use but often contained duplicates which somehow complicates the process. The `height` and the `width` of the images are determined by the most restrictive image (here, the third one because the top of the head reaches the top of the frame).

```
feats = First@FacialFeatures[#, "Landmarks"] & /@ imgs;
feats = KeyDrop[#, "MouthInternalPoints"] & /@ feats;
xcenter = Mean[#["OutlinePoints"][[{1, -1}, 1]]] & /@ feats;
ycenter = #["NosePoints"][[1, 2]] & /@ feats;
{widthMax, heightMax} = Floor[Min /@ Transpose[
     2*(ImageDimensions /@ imgs - Transpose[{xcenter, ycenter}])]];
height = heightMax
width = Round[3/4*height]
```

Now that the image sizes are defined, the four vertices of the targeted frame are added and centered on the face outline (vertically) and the nose (horizontally):

```
addCorners[feat_, {width_, height_}] := 
 Block[{feattmp = feat, xcenter, ycenter, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax},
  xcenter = feat["OutlinePoints"][[{1, -1}, 1]] // Mean;
  ycenter = feat["NosePoints"][[1, 2]];
  xmin = xcenter - width/2;
  xmax = xcenter + width/2;
  ymin = ycenter - height/2;
  ymax = ycenter + height/2;
  feattmp[
    "Corners"] = {{xmin, ymin}, {xmin, ymax}, {xmax, ymax}, {xmax, 
     ymin}};
  feattmp]

feats = addCorners[#, {width, height}] & /@ feats;

Table[HighlightImage[#, KeyValueMap[{Tooltip[#2, #1]} &, feats[[i]]]] &@imgs[[i]], 
   {i, Length@imgs}]
```

[image]

The images are then resized, the features points adapted accordingly:

```
 imgsCut = Table[ImageTrim[imgs[[i]], feats[[i]]["Corners"][[{1, 3}]]], {i, Length@imgs}]

points = Table[# - feat["Corners"][[1]] & /@ 
    Flatten[KeyValueMap[#2 &, feat], 1], {feat, feats}];
Table[HighlightImage[imgsCut[[i]], points[[i]]], {i, Length@imgsCut}]
```

[image]

Then, I reorder the image by "similarity" of the feature points (other criteria such as image distance might be more relevant):

```
g = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[DistanceMatrix[points]];
path = FindHamiltonianPath[g]
(* {5, 4, 2, 3, 1} *)
```

Then, the core:

```
(* i, starting image index; j, landing image index; step: smoothness of the animation *)
morph[i_, j_, step_] := 
 Block[{points1, points2, pointsMean, ldp, triangles1, triangles2, 
   mats, func, triangles, img1, img2, tab1, tab2},
  points1 = points[[i]];
  points2 = points[[j]];
  pointsMean = Mean /@ Transpose[{points[[i]], points[[j]]}];
  ldp = ListDensityPlot[ArrayPad[pointsMean, {0, {0, 1}}], 
    Mesh -> All, ColorFunction -> (White &)];
  trianglesOrder = First@Cases[ldp, Polygon[idx_] :> idx, Infinity];
  triangles1 = points1[[#]] & /@ trianglesOrder;
  triangles2 = points2[[#]] & /@ trianglesOrder;
  mats = Table[
    FindGeometricTransform[triangles2[[k]], triangles1[[k]], 
      TransformationClass -> "Affine"][[2, 1]], {k, 
     Length@triangles1}];
  func[{x_, y_}, coef_] := 
   Piecewise[
    Table[{TransformationFunction[
        coef*mats[[k]] + (1 - coef)*IdentityMatrix[3]][{x, y}], 
      inPolyQ[triangles1[[k]], {x, y}]}, {k, 1, 
      Length@triangles1}], {x, y}];
  triangles[coef_] := Map[func[#, 1 - coef] &, triangles1, {2}];
  img1[coef_] := 
   Graphics[{Texture[imgsCut[[i]]], 
     MapIndexed[
      Polygon[#, 
        VertexTextureCoordinates -> ({#[[1]]/width, #[[2]]/height} & /@
            triangles1[[First[#2]]])] &, triangles[coef]]}, 
    ImageSize -> {width, height}, PlotRangePadding -> None];
  img2[coef_] := 
   Graphics[{Texture[imgsCut[[j]]], 
     MapIndexed[
      Polygon[#, 
        VertexTextureCoordinates -> ({#[[1]]/width, #[[2]]/height} & /@
            triangles2[[First[#2]]])] &, triangles[1 - coef]]}, 
    ImageSize -> {width, height}, PlotRangePadding -> None];
  tab1 = Table[img1[coef], {coef, 0, 1, step}];
  tab2 = Table[img2[coef], {coef, 0, 1, step}];
  out = Table[
    Blend[{tab1[[-k]], tab2[[k]]}, (k - 1)/(Length[tab1] - 1)], {k, 1,
      Length[tab1]}];
  out]

inPolyQ[poly_, pt_] := Graphics`PolygonUtils`PointWindingNumber[poly, pt] =!= 0
```

Credits to:

- `andre314` (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/220452/18767) for an efficient piecewise affine transform
- `rm -rf` (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9417/18767) for `inPolyQ`

The principle is rather simple and common: perform a Delaunay mesh from the feature points, map each triangle from the origin image to the arrival image with an interpolation parameter (`coef`) that controls the smoothness of the transitions.

Then, the result:

```
pathCircular = path~Join~{path[[1]]};
out = ParallelTable[
   morph[pathCircular[[i]], pathCircular[[i + 1]], .1], {i, 
    Length[pathCircular] - 1}];

ListAnimate[Flatten@out]
```

[image]

(Poor quality due to 2Mb upload limitation)

**Showing the mesh** Simply add `FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], Triangle /@ triangles[coef]` in the `Graphics` of `img1` and the same with `1-coef` instead of `coef` in `img2` to show the triangular mesh:

[image]