# Information about how to use Texture

Tags: graphics, textures

Does anybody know where one can find understandable info about how Texture, VertexTextureCoordinates and TextureCoordinateFunction work?

Comment: I learned from the docs.

Comment: [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179518/5467) . I recommend to try the code in my answer.